# button onclick does not fire when its position is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox where onchange event adds some element at runtime. Due to this the submit button's position is changed. If user enters something in the textbox and clicks on the button the onclick event does not fire. I suspect its because at the same time the position of the button changes and browser thinks the click happened on page and not on the button.

Is there a way I can handle this situation? I can not move the button above the element which is added at runtime.

I have created a sample jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WV3Q8/3/

HTML:

```
<p>Enter something</p>
<input type="text" id="input" onchange="onChange()">
<div id="log"></div>
<button value="Go" style="display:block" type="button" onclick="submit();" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function onChange(){
    var value = $('#input').val();
    $('#log').append('<p>New value: ' + value + '</p>');
}

function submit(){
    alert('value submitted');
}
```

Edit 1

Test Case (Question is about 2nd test case) Its happening in all browsers (Chrome, IE 10 etc):

1. Enter something in the textbox and hit tab, p element is added and button's position is moved. Now click on submit button. An alert is shown.
2. Enter something in the textbox and click on the submit button. p element is added but the alert is not shown.

Edit 2:
I can not use other key events like keyup, keydown or keypress because of obvious reasons (they fire on every keypress). 
setimeout too is out of question since there are some radio buttons which are generated at runtime on the onchange event of textbox. Its no wise to click on submit button without showing these radio buttons to user.

Comment: It works fine in my Firefox

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome/Mac!

Comment: Works for me on Chrome. Elements changing positions shouldn't be a problem. Which browser does that occur on?

Comment: Same on Chrome, your JSfiddle works

Comment: Works for me in Firefox/Linux, which browser are you using?

Comment: Works for me on Chrome. Maybe you have to use "onblur"?

Comment: After changing the value of input, when you directly click on the button, the `onchange` event of input is fired rather than `onclick` of button

Comment: I have edited my question with two test cases. Its the second test case where due to the change in the position of the submit button the onclick event is missed. Its working fine for test case 1 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your edit #2 you have to delay the append  with `setTimeout()` method like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#log').append('<p>New value: ' + randomVal + '</p>');
},100);
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WV3Q8/6/)

Comment: In this solution user is not able to view the added element before the click of the button.

Answer (score 1):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WV3Q8/4/)
A way out is to use `onkeypress`

```
<input type="text" id="input" onkeypress="onChange();">
```

**UPDATE**
If it is possible for you to use `mousedown` event, it work's good.

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WV3Q8/16/)

Comment: I can not use keypress because it will fire on every key user presses. Need to user onblur or onchange.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a **return true** statement in *onChange()*

Here is the code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WV3Q8/9/)

```
function onChange(){
    var randomVal = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
    $('#log').append('<p>New value: ' + randomVal + '</p>');
    return true;
}

function submit(){
    alert('value submitted');
}
```

**EDIT**: Alternative solution might be calling onChange() inside submit().

Comment: The same problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `setTimeout`  with keyup event:

```
var time;

function onChange() {
    clearTimeout(time);
    time = setTimeout(function() {
        var value = $('#input').val();
        $('#log').append('<p>New value: ' + value + '</p>');
    }, 200);
}
```

It will append text once user finishes typing.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WV3Q8/8/

Answer (score 0):

This is not good solution but you can trigger the submit function for your case like this:

```
function onChange(){    
    var value = $('#input').val();
    $('#log').append('<p>New value: ' + value + '</p>');

    submit();
}

function submit(){

    alert('value submitted');


}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WV3Q8/15/)

Comment: With this solution, the submit will be called even if user click somewhere else (i.e. not on the submit button). As I mentioned in my 2nd Edit (in question) at runtime based on the input some radio buttons are added, so if user click on those radio buttons the submit will fire.

Comment: I found a method that will be okay for you http://jsfiddle.net/WV3Q8/21/ change the function in submit button to onChange()

Comment: The solution With http://jsfiddle.net/WV3Q8/21/ lost the functionality of textbox onchange.